# QXmlQuery - passing parameter to XSLT

Tags: c++, qt, xslt

Sample XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:param name="my-param" select="'none'"/>

<xsl:template match="sample">
  <html><body><p>
    parameter: <xsl:value-of select="$my-param"/>
  </p></body></html>
</xsl:template>
```

Sample XML:

```
<sample/>
```

Using `xmlpatterns` like so:

```
xmlpatterns sample.xsl sample.xml -param my-param=funky
```

I can make the HTML output read:

```
<html><body><p>
   parameter: funky</p></body></html>
```

Brilliant!

Q: How do I pass `my-param` to my XSLT using QXmlQuery?

I suspect it must be one of the `bindVariable()` overloads, but none seem a match for a simple string parameter.

Additional information in case it matters:
We are still using [Qt4.7](http://qt.apidoc.info/4.7.4/qxmlquery.html) at work.
But having had a quick look on the internet, the public interface for QXmlQuery seems no different in [Qt 5.x](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlquery.html)

**EDIT**

What I have so far:

```
QString output;

QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);
query.setFocus(QUrl(input_xml));
query.setQuery(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/sample.xsl"));
query.evaluateTo(&output);
```

I use `QXmlQuery::XSLT20` because it gives me the least headaches even though my XSLT is targeted at version 1.0 (just in case this has you confused)

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/xmlprocessing.html#qtxdm
It appears that you can just pass QVariants to bind. It implicitly constructs a QXmlItem from the variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `bindVariable` method effectively, but it depends on your XSLT, though.

If you have

```
<xsl:param name="my-param" select="$qt-var"/>
```

and later

```
parameter: <xsl:value-of select="$my-param"/>
```

This code will work as expected (please notice that variables must be bound *before* setting the query):

```
QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);
query.bindVariable("qt-var", QVariant("my value"));
query.setFocus(input_xml);
query.setQuery(xslt);
query.evaluateTo(&output);
```

If you omit the `xsl:param` declaration, and just have

```
parameter: <xsl:value-of select="$qt-var"/>
```

it will work as well.

You can still use *xmlpatterns*, as long as the `qt-var` is passed in:

```
xmlpatterns sample.xsl sample.xml -param qt-var=qtfunky
```

Comment: Yep, that works. Thanks also of course to @SteakOverflow who suggested the same.